# Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'visibility' of resource 'Group'

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When I try to apply a `$filter` clause to `/beta/groups` as follows:

```
$filter=resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team') and visibility eq 'Private'
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'visibility' of resource 'Group'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "eb6a7c7e-96da-4358-871d-e20ee5f82e2e",
            "date": "2020-01-09T23:25:01"
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. I copied the url you are using from microsoft's documentation for listing team sites with the ms graph and it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certain fields are not supported in a `$filter` clause. The `visibility` property is one such example.

Please see the [Group documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) for details on which properties support `$filter`. Filterable properties, such as `displayName`, include this in the property description:

> Returned by default. Supports `$filter` and `$orderby`.